# Stacked bar chart in matplotlib without hardcoding the fields

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple stacked bar chart using [this data](https://github.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs/blob/master/Activities.csv) **using ONLY matplotlib, pandas and numpy:**

- x-axis: Month
- Labels: activity type
- Height: distance

[image]

The examples I see, loop over the x-axis, but labels are always hard coded.

Can we loop over everything? In other words, can I create a chart without modifying this table:
[image]

No group by or pivot, just use the table as is and get the chart **using matplotlib, pandas and numpy only (learning those at the moment)**

Comment: [Please do not images of data/errors/code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). You can add the required data here to reproduce the example by printing the data frame, copy-pasting it inside the pair of three ticks ```.

Comment: I made the data available on one of my github accounts,( the link is in the post). That is not ok?  
The image there only is to show the data without having to go to github for a quick review of the question.